# Why does RPM think version 1.03ii > 1.1?

Tags: python, packaging, rpm, yum

I am attempting to upgrade an RPM that was previously at version `1.03ii-1` with the newest version of the package at `1.1-1`.

Yum, for some reason, thinks that `1.03ii-1` is *newer* than `1.1-1`. Neither package has an epoch, and `rpm.labelCompare(('1', '1.03ii', '1'), ('1','1.1','1'))` in python also implies that `1.03ii-1` is *higher* than `1.1-1`.

Why is this? Is `ii` getting evaluated as numeric somehow? Does an alphanumeric version get treated as higher than just a numeric one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://rpm5.org/docs/api/dependencies.html, emphasis mine

> The algorithm that RPM uses to determine the version ordering of
>   packages is simple and developers are encouraged not to rely on the
>   details of its working. Developers should keep their numbering scheme
>   simple so any reasonable ordering algorithm would work. The version
>   comparison algorithm is in the routine rpmvercmp() and it is just a
>   segmented strcmp(3). First, the boundaries of the segments are found
>   using isdigit(3)/isalpha(3). Each segment is then compared in order
>   with the right most segment being the least significant. The
>   alphabetical portions are compared using a lexical graphical ascii
>   ordering, the digit segments strip leading zeroes and compare the
>   strlen before doing a strcmp. If both numerical strings are equal, the
>   longer string is larger. **Notice that the algorithm has no knowledge
>   of decimal fractions, and perl-5.6 is "older" than perl-5.00503
>   because the number 6 is less than the number 503.**

In this case the versions are converted to the tuples (1,3,'ii') and (1,1). The first element is equal so the second is compared with 3 > 1 so 1.03ii is considered newer than 1.1

Comment: Well, that certainly explains it. Thanks for the excellent answer.